# How to get all the matched data from an api using clojure

Tags: clojure

I have written a clojure code

```
(select-keys (some #(if (= date (get % :date)) %)
         (read data))
         [:id :uuid [:type :text]])
```

The data is taken from an api.(read data) contains all the data from the api.

The api data is of the form

[
{
id:
uuid:
type: {
    parent:
    text:
}
date:
},

{
id:
uuid:
type: {
    parent:
    text:
}
date:
}
.
.
.
.
.
.
}]

with many nested-loops.
I want :id,:uuid and text values if the date is matched.
when I use some it gives only the first logically true, how to get all set values if multiple sets have same dates.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: [
{
  id: 1989,
  uuid: "A234J",
  type:  {
  uuid: "435J0",
  name: "Kim",
  parent: "jack",
  },
  date: "2016-08-03T18:45:00Z",
},
{
  id: 1990,
  uuid: "A235J",
  type:  {
  uuid: "436J0",
  name: "lee",
  parent: "jill",
  },
  date: "2016-09-03T18:45:00Z",
}
]

Comment: Please check the answer below, as well as all the answers to other questions of yours other people provided you with over the last few weeks. If you are satisfied with some of them, please accept them. If not, please clarify your intentions and make it clear **why** the provided answers didn't satisfy you. That's the least you can do to repay people for the time and effort they put in answering your questions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry. I am very new here

Comment: Did that work for you? It's giving me an error (ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.util.Map  clojure.lang.RT.find)

Comment: Check the update. No, I didn't run it - I mentioned that. Your data is in the form which is impossible to use. Next time just copy it from the REPL.

Comment: By the way, next time you add comments, please mention the person name with @ like you probably see around. This way we receive a message about your comment and have a chance to respond quicker.

Comment: @YuriSteinschreiber I tried and still a bad luck to me.. It didn't work

Comment: Paste your data from REPL.

Comment: See update. Last one was a simple typo - missing blank between `:date` and `%`. Make sure you supply a copy of data and code each time you ask a question, makes it much easier to answer.

Comment: @YuriSteinschreiber But this doesn't give data for all dates and also no data for text?

Comment: @YuriSteinschreiber My mistake sorry. It gives data for all dates. but not the  nested values.

Comment: Look at get-in. If it's unclear ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `filter` instead of `some`. As you noticed yourself, `some` returns the first true value of the collection; `filter` returns a collection of all values satisfying the predicate.

Your predicate can be simplified: `#(= date (:date %))`

So try the following (just changing your snippet, it's impossible to run anything with scarce and unformatted data you've provided.)

Update: was concentrated on the filter part. Of course you need a `map` over the sequence produced by `filter`:

```
(map #(select-keys % [:id :uuid [:type :text]]) 
     (filter #(= date (:date %))
             (read data)))
```

With your sample data:

```
(def data '({:id 17592186110311, :uuid "a0033f78-4a4c-4464-95ab-80d73c3cb354", :assessment-type {:questionnaire-complete? false, :questionnaire-started? false, :parent nil, :assessment_types [{:uuid "87bfa9e4-c55a-11e5-8f63-22564765227c", :name "Basic"} {:uuid "87bfaa16-c55a-11e5-8f63-22564765227c", :name "Comprehensive"}], :name "HEART", :uuid "87bfa980-c55a-11e5-8f63-22564765227c", :heart? false, :text "/HEART"}, :client "9f80d05d-156b-11e5-a9f1-5254001815f0", :date "2016-08-30T13:15:00Z", :skip-ess true, :created-at "2016-08-30T20:02:24Z"}) )

(def date  "2016-08-30T13:15:00Z")

(defn try-it [date]
  (map #(select-keys % [:id :uuid [:type :text]]) 
       (filter #(= date (:date %))
               data)))

(try-it date);; => ({:id 17592186110311, :uuid "a0033f78-4a4c-4464-95ab-80d73c3cb354"})
```

Comment: That's a different question in fact. You stated your problem as inability to access all elements in the sequence satisfying the predicate, as opposed to only the first one. This one is solved. Now you are asking how to access embedded values in a multilevel map. Maybe mark this question as answered already, otherwise the entire thread becomes confusing. Look at core get-in function in the meantime.